# Edit Properties and Rename Page buttons are disabled on the Sharepoint 2010 Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, ribbon

This problem only occurs in my locally installed Sharepoint Foundation 2010, though everything's ok in my Sharepoint Server (on my virtual machine). In Sharepoint Foundation I can't  still add web-parts nor rename the page because the required buttons are disabled. The pop-up message says "This control is currently disabled". All the permissions are inherited from the site collection where I am in all proper groups (my account name is everywhree). The Reference guide under F2 pressed provides some basic useless help, like I don't have enough permissions or some services are be disabled an so on. So how can I have these controls enabled?

Comment: Which buttons exactly are disabled? "Edit Properties"? Try logging in as a site collection administrator just to check out whether these buttons are always disabled or if it is a permission problem - it usually is.

Comment: Yes, "Edit Properies" and "Rename Page". I am the only site collection administrator. No other accounts but the one I log in with are added into this group.

Comment: This is a valid question, other environments show the same behavior, on SharePoint 2013 as well, disabled buttons for site collection admin in the ribbon while viewing the page, but the same actions are available from pages library views that list all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your site is on read only (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/240642)
It may happen when a backup fails.